# How can I get the running average for each date, but the average is for values from the beginning of time till that date?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table that has two columns, date and value.

```
Date        Value
3/1/2023    1
3/1/2023    5
3/2/2023    6
3/2/2023    8
3/3/2023    15
```

The result of my SQL Query should be this:

```
Date        Value
3/1/2023    3   (1+5   / 2 = 3)
3/2/2023    5   (1+5+6+8   / 4 = 5)
3/3/2023    7   (1+5+6+8+15   / 5 = 7)
```

Here, I do not want to calculate the running query for each day separately. I want ALL records from the min date up until that date.

I have tried using this query:

```
SELECT date, AVG(value) as running_avg
FROM test
WHERE date BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(date) FROM test) AND date
GROUP BY date;
```

But if I want to have the result I want, I need to group by date, but this will counteract the logic I want. Anyone know a workaround?

Comment: What's the name of your RDMS?

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server, you can do:

```
CREATE TABLE SampleTable (
    Date DATE,
    Value INT
);

INSERT INTO SampleTable (Date, Value)
VALUES ('2023-03-01', 1),
       ('2023-03-01', 5),
       ('2023-03-02', 6),
       ('2023-03-02', 8),
       ('2023-03-03', 15);

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES date, avg_value
FROM
(
    SELECT *
          ,AVG(value * 1.0) OVER (ORDER BY Date ASC) AS avg_value
    FROM SampleTable
) DS
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY avg_value DESC)
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

You need first to calculate the running average. We are doing this with the following:

```
AVG(value * 1.0) OVER (ORDER BY Date ASC)
```

but this is not good, as we have same dates, so it will be better to order by id or something else in order to make the ordering deterministic.

The second part is to get the last record of each date. We are using `TOP 1 WITH TIES` and:

```
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY avg_value DESC)
```

Again, this is not good as I am counting that the average running value will increase, but in reality, this is not always true. So, you need to have a way to order the rows by id again.